# It should not insert values from php to database if these already exist

Tags: php, mysql, database

Iam using a form in php to insert some values in my database. As you can see i retrieve from the form 4 values, id, name ,price and quantity. What i want to do is insert the values in the database table named catalog but only if id retrieved is not in the database before. The user cannot add id that exists.

I made an if that takes the results from select (*) count where id=$id. If the results is =0 then it should insert the values, else it should not and echo that id already exists. Unfortunately whatever i do, it keeps echoing that id already exists, and doesnt inserts the values in the catalog.

Any help and ideas would be appreciated :)

```
    <?php
include("mysql.php");
    session_start();
    $link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
    mysql_select_db($database);
    echo "<center>";
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $price=$_POST['price'];
    $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
    $sql="select count(*) from catalog";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$id || !$name || !$price || !$quantity)
    die("You should write all the fields in form");
    if ($sql=0)
    {
    $sql="insert into catalog values ('$id','$name','$price','$quantity')";
    }
    else 
        echo "id exists";
    if(mysql_query($sql))
    echo "Insert Successful<br><br>";
    else
    echo "<br>Insert NOT Successful<br><br><br>";
?>
```

Comment: `if ($sql=0)` $sql in this case is just a string; and to compare you use `==` - your check really makes no senses on several levels

Comment: Panagiotis please mark and up-vote the answer for others help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well couldnt do it as with that code but thanks for the help everybody.

Tried this and worked.

```
<?php
session_start();
$linu=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("eshop");
$id=$_POST['id'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$price=$_POST['price'];
$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
$sql="select * from catalog where id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$N=mysql_num_rows($result);
if(!$id || !$name || !$price || !$quantity)
die("You should write all the fields in form");
if($N==1)
    echo "id exists";
else
$sql2="insert into catalog values ('$id','$name','$price','$quantity')";
if(mysql_query($sql2))
{
echo "Insert Successful<br><br>";
}
else
{
echo "<br>Insert NOT Successful<br><br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, why not just set a unique constraint on the columns in mysql if you don't want something existing to be inserted? That's an overall better solution to a problem like that in your title.

Secondly, in your code you are saying if $sql can be set to 0, not if $sql == 0 in the statement `if ($sql=0)`. This will always return true because you are able to set $sql to 0.

Thirdly, you don't seem to understand what $result is what contains the result of your query, or what $result is.

I think you need to read more tutorials and get a  better understanding of what you're doing.

Comment: ie - nuke it from space - start again